# How can I load an ISO file into RAM and boot from it?

Tags: linux

Is it possible to use a tool to load an ISO file into RAM and then boot from it? LiveCDs inject into RAM and boot from it, if I'm correct. So can I just bypass the program and load it into RAM and boot it before the memory clears?

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to investigate [MEMDISK](http://www.etherboot.org/wiki/bootingmemdisk) as this would seem to be the answer to what you are trying to do.

LiveCD's are, I believe, a little different.  (Like most Linux systems) they boot a minimal system using [initrd](http://On%20a%20standard%20X86%20system,%20not%20practically.%20%20It%20might%20be%20possible%20to%20write%20a%20driver%20to%20do%20this%20in%20the%20UEFI,%20but%20it%20would%20be%20orders%20of%20magnitude%20easier%20(and%20probably%20more%20portable)%20to%20create%20a%20minimal%20boot%20environment%20which%20specifies%20an%20image%20to%20copy%20into%20memory%20after%20the%20OS%20has%20loaded%20-%20at%20the%20cost%20of%20the%20image%20needing%20to%20be%20compatible%20with%20the%20already%20booted%20disk%20image%20or%20kernel.%20%20This%20is%20largely%20similar%20to%20what%20[initrd][1]%20does%20on%20a%20typical%20system.) and then create the full blown experience in RAM from that - but the kernel/OS is loaded prior to everything being put into memory.